# Allow Cross-Origin-Ressource Sharing R-Studio Server/Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, cors, shiny, cross-domain

I am hosting a Shiny App on R-Studio Server. The App created through Shiny is a Browser App. That means JavaScript is executed from the Client site. In my App I create several through user interaction, which are saved on localhost/webserver. I then want to access these files in JavaScript and process them in there. And thats where the trouble starts...

This is `cross-origin-ressource-sharing` and I cannot make a `Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest` since this is forbidden due to security reasons. How am I supposed to access the files in JavaScript? When I pass a relative/absolute path to the files I get

I pass a link like so `path/to/file.json` and when I check in the console, javascript changes it to something like `localhost:numbererOfPort/path/to/file`. When I type that into the browser there is nothing. On my filesystem the file is under `path/to/file`, without the `localhost...`

> Failed to load resource: the server responded http://localhost...json with a status of 404 (Not Found).

I had a look [JONSP](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/) but I don't think thats what I am looking for since I am not docking onto an API but rather a file, saved on disk.
I also tried to loosen the security settings of Chrome by installing an extension that turns on/off CORS.
I am still getting this message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load xy. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: If it throws a 404 that's not a problem with CORS. CORS itself can be enabled with setting the correct headers, especially Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @SargoDarya I added some Information where the `404` might come from.

Comment: What do you mean by "access these files in javascript and process them in there"?

Comment: @warmoverflow I want to load `.json` files into JavaScript for working with them there. something like `d3.json(...)`

Comment: I think, if you put your json file in the `www` subfolder of your app, then you can access the file using `http://localhost:3838/app_directory/file.json` (no `www` here). Then it should work. This is not related to CORS. as long as you can access the file using your browser, you can do it within Javascript.

Comment: @warmoverflow oh wow, I did not know that. Can I have a substructure of folders in the `www` folder? There will be many files and some structure is needed rather than many files in one files... I will try it and let you know!

Comment: @warmoverflow it works. thanks a lot. You wanna write that down as an answer?! I think that might be helpful for others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Shiny, static files (like images, css and javascript files) should be put in the `www` subfolder under the app folder. These files can then be accessed in Shiny code using relative path (but without `www` part) or in web browser using `http://host_name:port/app_directory/file.name` (again without `www`).